# Is there a way to programmatically determine the location of my sublime executable?

Tags: bash

For example, for command-line programs I just use

```
which git // return path of git
```

Is there something similar for programs like sublime?

Obviously, I could poke around and find it but I was hoping there was something like `which`

Comment: How do you run it? What OS / desktop manager ?

Comment: I'm in a bash shell on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you want but if you have locate activated you can do a

```
locate -i -l 1 "sublime text 2.app"
```

or

```
locate -i -l 1 "sublime text.app"
```

depending on version (2 or 3-beta).

Remove -l 1 på list all matches for the text.

If locate is not active you might want to do a

```
find / -name "Sublime Text 2.app" 2> /dev/null
```

or

```
find / -name "Sublime Text.app" 2> /dev/null
```